# search and display records using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

For past hours now i have been trying to display database records as user types email address instantly. it seems the rendering properties is not displaying the result. Again since am trying to display results using **dangerouslySetInnerHTML()**, do 
`dataType: 'json'` be set to `dataType: 'html'`. it also shows error **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello World</title>



<script src="build/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/browser.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/jquery.min.js"></script>



  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">

class NameForm extends React.Component {


  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
 this.state = {value: ''};
this.state = {email: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }





 handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  }

  componentDidMount() {

$(".search").keyup(function() 
{


    $.ajax({

 url: "search.php",
       type: "POST",
       //dataType: 'html',
       //ContentType: 'application/json',
       success: function(data) {
        email: this.state.email;

         this.setState({data: data});
       }.bind(this),
       error: function(jqXHR) {
         console.log(jqXHR);
       }.bind(this)
    })
})// end search

  }




render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <label>Search by Email:
          <input className="search" id="email" name="email" type="text" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>

        {
         this.state.data ?
           <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.data}} />
          : <div>Loading...</div>
        }
      </div>
   );    
}



}
ReactDOM.render(
  <NameForm />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);


 </script>




  </body>
</html>
```

**search.php**

```
<?php
include('db.php');
if($_POST)
{
$gg=strip_tags($_POST['email']);
$q=htmlentities($gg);


//$q=$_POST['searchword'];

$result = $db->prepare("select * from group_data where group_name like :group_name or group_name1 like :group_name1 order by id LIMIT 20");


$result->execute(array(
':group_name' => '%'.$q.'%', 
':group_name1' => '%'.$q.'%'
));





while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
$gn=htmlentities($row['group_name'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
$gn1=htmlentities($row['group_name1'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");



?>
<div class="display_box" align="left">


<span style="font-size:9px; color:#999999"><?php echo $gn; ?></span></div>



<?php
}

}
else
{

}


?>
```

Can someone help me fix the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your results are never shown because you are just returning the label and the input, the other return is never reached.

So in order to get your code to work, your render should go like this:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div> //Remember to wrap it in a div, render should only return one root element
        <label>Search by Email:
          <input className="search" id="email" name="email" type="text" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>

        {
         this.state.data ?
           <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.data}} />
          : <div>Loading...</div>
        }
      </div>
   );    
}
```

You can check a working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jalissa/bxstedzb/1/).

**EDIT:**

To fix the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined` you need to bind the component to the callback of the keyup too.

Like this: `$(".search").keyup(function() { ... }.bind(this)) // end search`

Comment: Thanks for your help so far but  error occured when searching  "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined". i have updated my question to also show the database side. thanks

Comment: @bowman87 That is because you are binding `this` to your success and error callbacks when `this` is the element that is triggering the keyup event. You need to bind the component to the callback of the keyup too.
Like this:  `$(".search").keyup(function() { ... }.bind(this)) // end search`

Comment: you could also delete this line `email: this.state.email;` it doesn't seem like you're using it. And, if you want to declare an email variable, the code should be like this: `var email =  this.state.email;`